# How should we handle a bounty that is not being paid?

Tags: support, bounty

I spent an hour answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378496/how-to-find-integer-and-text-values-filter-search/72428907#72428907) because it had a bounty. I spun up a test app, provided actual data (SQL), code (PowerFX), and an illustration (animated .gif) showing the results. The OP basically said, "Newp, doesn't work for me" without any error messages, screenshots, etc. The bounty has now lapsed.

How does the Stack Overflow bounty system handle this type of situation?

Comment: It looks like the bounty isn't gone, it can still be assigned: "This bounty has ended. Answers to this question are eligible for a +50 reputation bounty. **Bounty grace period ends in 8 hours.**"

Comment: What exactly do you want handled here? A bounty isn't some kind of advance payment, nor compensation for effort. It can be assigned - or not assigned - for almost any reason the OP feels like. Not solving the problem seems like a good reason, TBH, and judging by the comments and edits the OP *did* try to provide you with the information requested.

Comment: “How does the StackOverflow bounty system handle this type of situation?” - Absolutely nothing; A bounty does not have to be awarded, just for your information asking the author to award to your answer, is unacceptable so absolutely DO NOT do that.

Comment: **Point taken:** Don't spend any additional time on bounty questions.

Comment: Right. Seriously, don't. Bounties are something "paid" by the person who wants an answer in order to "feature" a question, thus making it more prominent and thus (so the idea goes) more likely to receive an answer. (Good evidence for this in the design is the fact that you still lose the rep paid for the bounty even if there are no answers.) Bounties aren't primarily intended for the answerer; you should be writing good, high-quality, helpful answers to *all* questions, regardless. The existence of a bounty shouldn't be a reason why you do more work. Or why you choose to answer at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the most literal sense, Stack Overflow *does* do something but only because there's a very specific case here.

In general - if the person offering the bounty chooses not to offer the bounty, then there are multiple things that could happen:

- If any answer has, *after* the bounty has been posted, been added *and* has a score of 2 or more, then the highest scoring answer would win 50% of the bounty.
- If there are multiple answers added after the bounty has started with the same score, then the oldest is chosen.
- If there is no answer scored above 2 or there is no "oldest" answer, then no bounty is awarded.

Because it looks like you're the only person who answered it *and* your post doesn't have a positive score of 2, then you won't be awarded anything.

Not much you can do about that, really.  There's never been any implicit guarantee that a bounty can be awarded.

Your goal is more oriented around helping the OP, and if they said that they weren't helped, then others in the community would have to disagree with the OP (this isn't that high a hurdle as you may think) and vote on your answer so that you could get *some* of the bounty.

Comment: There's a fourth option for the bounty too: the answerer pesters with a comment like ["So... wheres the bounty?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378496/how-to-find-integer-and-text-values-filter-search/72428907#comment128067222_72428907)

Comment: While comments like that do work surprisingly well, a more *efficient* way to attract the attention of moderators is to simply raise a moderator flag, @francescalus. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray To fulfill my curiosity, could you elaborate on what would be accomplished by raising the moderator flag? Would the mods nudge the bounty setter to award an answerer? Or do they actually have the ability to award the bounty themselves?

Comment: @ClintWarner I'm afraid Cody was engaging in their trademark deadpan sarcasm here.  That was referring to the fact that leaving a "So... wheres the bounty?" comment will have the primary effect of attracting a moderator to the post to delete said comment, much as a flag would also attract a moderator's attention.  In other words: don't leave such comments.  For better or worse, there's not much moderators can do to encourage attentiveness to bounties.

Comment: @RyanM Duly noted! Good thing I was definitely _not_ in the midst of typing one of these comments when I received your response...